# Filter newline from exec output with Ant

Tags: svn, ant

We have a huge and old Ant build file for our project.

A few days ago, one of the targets broke. It calls `svnversion` and writes the version to a .java file. Suddenly there is a line break in the string and the compiler complains because of:

```
String version = "Foo
 bar";
```

I have little experience with Ant and I have a very hard time understanding the documentation. I think some sort of 'filterchain' would do the trick, but I can't get it to work.

Here the build target:

```
<target name="svnversion">
  <exec executable="svnversion" dir="${basedir}" outputproperty="svnversion">
    <arg value="${basedir}"/>
    <arg value="/dev/projects/${project.name}/trunk/"/>
  </exec>
<echo message="svnversion ${svnversion}"/>
```

It runs on Windows. I simply want to replace any "\n" or "\n\r" with nothing.

Oddly enough, if I run `svnversion` in cmd manually, I don't see a line break in the output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svnversion --help
...
Valid options:
  -n [--no-newline]        : do not output the trailing newline
```

Just add `-n` to command-line options

Comment: Accepted answer bc. simple, easy, uses the right tool. No need to go via some complicated Ant markup. 10/10 would ask again ;)

Answer (score 1):

A generic way would be using [loadresource](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html) to create a new property based on altered exec outputproperty, f.e. :

```
<loadresource property="foo">
 <propertyresource name="svnversion"/>
 <filterchain>
  <striplinebreaks/>
 </filterchain>
</loadresource>

<!-- new property foo without linebreak -->
<echo>$${foo} => ${foo}</echo>
```